# How to pass data from Node.js to html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple program and some data strings that I want to pass to HTML page that hosted locally, but I'm getting error: ReferenceError: document is not defined

There's my .js file **index.js:**

```
let some_string = "some data";

document.getElementById("dataButton").onclick = function(){
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    var text = document.createTextNode(some_string); 
    paragraph.appendChild(text);
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    element.appendChild(paragraph);
}
```

And there's my HTML **test.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>New title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Data page</h1>

    <button id="dataButton">Add data</button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Many thanks if someone come up with idea what am I doing wrong!

Comment: are you running your project with `node index.js`, you should just open index.html in your browser without running nodejs

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly but I want to run program, since it will be real time update on it, and pass data to html

Answer (score 0):

Update your files to the following

```js
let some_string = "some data";
const dataButton = document.getElementById("dataButton");

dataButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  var text = document.createTextNode(some_string);
  paragraph.appendChild(text);
  var element = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  element.appendChild(paragraph);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>New title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Data page</h1>
    <button id="dataButton">Add data</button>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im still getting ReferenceError: document is not defined, from what I googled I see that I can't update html since Im using server-side program, is there any way to deal with it?

Comment: Can you update your answer with the snippet of the error you are getting ?

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow and dont know how to add snippet of error, Im running it through index.js since it would be some program that will work with some real time data

Comment: okay can you then just copy paste the whole error message

Comment: sorry for long response: Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: Can u put ur project in a github repository and share it?